# How can I improve code for this circuit diagram?

Tags: circuitikz

How can I improve this code? I would like to know if there is a better way of doing this. Also, is there some way that I can change the dimensions of the circuit diagram without needing to manually change the numbers?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{circuitikz}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
\begin{circuitikz}

\coordinate (C) at (3.9,1.5);
\coordinate (R) at (4,5);
\coordinate (A) at (6,5);
\coordinate (B) at (6,1.45);
\coordinate (D) at (-1, 3.5);

\draw (0,0) to[vsourcesin] (0,7);
\draw (0,7) to (5,7);
\draw[stealth-] (5,6) to (6,6);
\node at (A) {$V_r$};
\draw (6,6) to (6,5.4);
\draw (6,4) to (6,4.6);
\draw[stealth-] (5,4) to (6,4);
\draw (5,7) to[generic] (5,3);
\node at (R) {$10K$};
\draw (5,3) to[capacitor] (5,0);
\node at (C) {$0.1\mu F$};
\draw[stealth-] (5,2.2) to (6,2.2);
\draw (6,2.2) to (6,1.7);
\node at (B) {$V_c$};
\draw (6,1.25) to (6,0.8);
\draw[stealth-] (5,0.8) to (6, 0.8);
\draw (5,0) to (0,0);
\node at (D) {$V_{\textrm{in}}$};
\draw[stealth-] (0,2.45) to (-1.1,2.45);
\draw[stealth-] (0,4.5) to (-1.1,4.5);
\draw (-1.1, 4.5) to (-1.1, 3.82);
\draw(-1.1, 3.23) to (-1.1, 2.45);

\end{circuitikz}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

This code produces:

[image]

original image

[image]

Comment: Just wondering, what you want: a) beautiful code? b) a 1:1 copy of the original translated into Tikz?

Comment: @MS-SPO Beautiful code.

Comment: Ok. All you need to do is adopting the convention as described in the circuitikz manual. See also Markos answer and the code posted there. Learn from it and replace all your node/draw entries.

Comment: Suggestion for the voltage drops notation: either a) remove one of the two arrows or b) add a `+` to one of them. Sorry to be insistent, call it professional deformation (I teach electronics), but as it is, you can't write KVL for the circuit in an unambiguous way.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your circuit scheme is a bit unusual ... In MWE below are code for two ways, how to draw it:

- usual (standardised) way
- as you like to get

```
\documentclass[margin=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage[siunitx]{circuitikz}
\usetikzlibrary{ext.paths.ortho}

\begin{document}

\begin{circuitikz}[european]
\ctikzset{bipoles/capacitor/height=0.5,
          bipoles/capacitor/width/.initial=.1,
          resistors/scale=0.8, 
          voltage/bump b=20pt,voltage/european label distance=1pt
          }
%
\draw (0,0) to[vsourcesin, v=$V_\mathrm{in}$, voltage/european label distance=1.3pt] ++(0,4)   
            to[short] ++ (3,0)
            to[R, a=10<\kilo\ohm>, v^=$V_f$] ++(0,-2)  %   , a=10<\kilo\ohm>\)
            to[C, a=0.1<\micro\farad>,v^=$V_c$] ++(0,-2)  %   , a=0,1<\micri\farad>\)
            to[short, -.] ++ (-3,0);
\end{circuitikz}

\quad and \quad
\begin{circuitikz}[european,
lbl/.style = {midway, fill=white, inner sep=2pt}
                  ]
\ctikzset{bipoles/capacitor/height=0.5,
          bipoles/capacitor/width/.initial=.1
         }
%
\draw (0,0) to[vsourcesin, name=V] ++(0,4)
            to[short] ++ (3,0)
            to[R, a=10<\kilo\ohm>,name=R] ++(0,-2) 
            to[C, a=0.1<\micro\farad>, name=C] ++(0,-2) 
            to[short, -.] ++ (-3,0);
\draw[<->]  ([yshift=2mm] V.east) -|- [distance=-9mm] ([yshift=-2mm] V.west) node[lbl] {$V_{\mathrm{in}}$};
\draw[<->]  ([yshift=2mm] R.west) -|- [distance= 9mm] ([yshift=-2mm] R.east) node[lbl] {$V_f$};
\draw[<->]  ([yshift=4mm] C.west) -|- [distance= 9mm] ([yshift=-4mm] C.east) node[lbl] {$V_c$};
\end{circuitikz}

\end{document}
```

[image]

**Addendum:**
For those who use Overleaf, which does not yet have the ext.paths.ortho package installed, a "classic" solution without using this library:

```
\documentclass[margin=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage[siunitx]{circuitikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,
                ext.paths.ortho}

\begin{document}

\ctikzset{bipoles/capacitor/height=0.5,
          bipoles/capacitor/width/.initial=.1,
          resistors/scale=0.8,
          voltage/bump b=20pt,voltage/european label distance=1pt
          }
\begin{circuitikz}[european,
         > = Straight Barb,
lbl/.style = {midway, fill=white, inner sep=2pt, pos=0.25}
                  ]
\ctikzset{bipoles/capacitor/height=0.5,
          bipoles/capacitor/width/.initial=.1
         }
%
\draw (0,0) to[vsourcesin, name=V] ++(0,4)
            to[short] ++ (3,0)
            to[R, a=10<\kilo\ohm>,name=R] ++(0,-2)   
            to[C, a=0.1<\micro\farad>, name=C] ++(0,-2)  
            to[short, -.] ++ (-3,0);
\draw[<->]  ([yshift=2mm] V.east) -- ++ (-9mm,0) |- ([yshift=-2mm] V.west) node[lbl] {$V_{\mathrm{in}}$};
\draw[<->]  ([yshift=2mm] R.west) -- ++ (+9mm,0) |- ([yshift=-2mm] R.east) node[lbl] {$V_f$};
\draw[<->]  ([yshift=4mm] C.west) -- ++ (+9mm,0) |- ([yshift=-4mm] C.east) node[lbl] {$V_c$};
\end{circuitikz}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: What is ```\usetikzlibrary{ext.paths.ortho} ```

Comment: @Ajay, this is package which can be load as Ti*k*Z library, written  by  Qrrbrbirlbel, available on CTAN: https://ctan.org/pkg/tikz-ext?lang=en. It provide syntax for arrows like `-|-` lines as are used in my answer. Very useful and may others. For details see package documentation

Comment: The second diagram doesn't render in overleaf. It cannot parse the coordinates.

Comment: @Ajay, I'm afraid that the package is to new, that be already included to Overleaf (as I remember, its team refresh installation ones per year at autom). This means, that you need to add it yourself. How to do this please ask its support or google this site (I'm not familiar with Overleaf).

Comment: @Ajay, You not mentioned, that you use Overleaf. However, I would add "classic" way to draw lines  ASAP.

Comment: It works now. Thanks.

Comment: +1, extensive answer. @Ajay, notice that the way you are marking the voltage drops is ambiguous: you do not know which is the (assumed) polarity.